# ¿Cómo ejecutar una función antes de que submit haga la validación del formulario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, validación, submit

Tengo un formulario bastante grande. Algunos de los campos los he divido por secciones y se pueden ocultar con Toggle() para que no molesten mientras se rellenan los demás campos. El prolema aparece cuando el usuario envia los datos. Al hacer click en submit se hace una validacón automática y obtengo errores como este.

```
An invalid form control with name='Name' is not focusable.
```

Pensaba que haciendo algo así lo podría solucionar:

```
$("#form").on("submit" ,function()
{   
    for(var i=0; i<7;i++)
    {
        var id = "#toggle"+ (i+1);
        $(id).addClass("show");

    }   
});
```

Pero en este caso el método no se llega a ejecutar porque los errores aparecen primero.

También he intentado hacerlo así, sustituyendo el submit por un botón normal:

```
$("#enviar").on("click" ,function()
{
    for(var i=0; i<7;i++)
    {
            var id = "#toggle"+ (i+1);
            $(id).addClass("show");
    }
    $("#form").submit();
});
```

En este otro caso no tengo errores pero el formulario se envia sin ser validado.

¿Alguna forma de ejecutar el método antes de que se haga la validación del formulario? Es decir, ejecutarlo para que no haya errores y además sin perder la validación.

Comment: con que estas validando???

Comment: Lo único que tengo puesto es la etiqueta "required" en algunos campos para asegurarme de que no se quedan vacios..

Comment: Que tiene tu clase show de css pk parece ser que nos e valida pk no se estan mostrando a la hora de hacer el submit

Comment: No lo sé... es una clase de bootstrap... al añadir esa clase hace que el Toggle se abra. Si es exactamente por eso!! por eso quiero abrirlos todos antes de hacer el submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de esta forma. Ocultando el submit y haciendo click en él a través de otro botón después de desplegar todos los toggles.

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" style="visibility:hidden">Enviar</button> 

<button type="button" id="btn"">Enviar</button>

$("#btn").on("click" ,function()
{

    for(var i=0; i<7;i++)
    {
        var id = "#toggle"+ (i+1);
        $(id).addClass("show");
    }
    $("#submit").click();
});
```

De esta forma he conseguido que no salgan errores y no perder la validación automática del formulario.

Pero si alguien sabe otro camino mas "elegante" para hacer lo mismo sería estupendo que lo dijera.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes quitar el boton de submit ya que no lo usas, y al final en lugar de hacer un `$("#submit").click();` haces un `$("#form").submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Porque no en lugar de un boton submit colocas uno normal con una funcion onclick

```
 function enviar(){
  var formulario = document.getElementById("myform");   
  //Aqui tu codigo para mostrar tus objetos
  formulario.submit();
}
```

Comment: voy a probar... a ver si así no no se pierde la validación... Ahora te digo si funciona...

Comment: Al hacerlo como tu dices no se envia el formulario... Se abren todo los toogels pero el submit no funciona!!

Comment: Y te dice algún error en la consola talvez no estas tomando bien el formulario? intenta con :
document.forms["myform"].submit();

Comment: Si, me sale este error **formulario.submit is not a function**

Comment: Quitaste el boton de submit que tenias? asegurate de cambiar el tipo del botón no le dejes submit

Comment: Si, lo quité y puse un botón normal... y además probé a intentar enviar el formulario tambien usando JQuery. poniendo esto **$("#form").submit();** en vez de esto **formulario.submit();** pero tampoco funciona... ni idea de porqué!!

Comment: ya lo he solucionado!! :-) ... ahora te digo como lo hice!!

Comment: Lo he puesto ahí arriba... Oye!! Gracias por intetar ayudarme!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

No se jQuery pero con Javascript puedes utilizar [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para cancelar un evento, es decir, no hacer el submit. Así puedes ejecutar el método antes de enviarlo.
[Aquí](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) está en la documentación de jQuery.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @Tiveruis, pero quería conservar el comportamiento por defecto que era la validación del formulario... al final conseguí hacerlo ocultando el submit... por ahí puse la respuesta. Saludos!!